# How do I declare an array of elements that all implement an interface?

Tags: typescript

The `push` method is called with any of several different requests that all implement the interfaces in the signature.

How can I change this code so that I don't need to use the any keyword in `Array<ActiveRequest<any>>`?

```
interface ActiveRequest<TServerResponse extends IServerResponse> {
    resolve: (value: TServerResponse) => void;
    ...
}

export class Connection {
    protected activeRequests: Array<ActiveRequest<any>>;
    constructor(...) {
        this.activeRequests = [];
        ...
    }

    public push<TRequestBody extends IRequestBody, TServerResponse extends IServerResponse>(
        requestBody: TRequestBody, 
        resolve: (value: TServerResponse) => void, 
    )
    ...

    this.activeRequests.push({
        resolve,
        ...
    });
}
```

Here is an example of how `push` is invoked:

```
export interface CreateProjectRequestBody extends IRequestBody {
    cmd: 'otii_create_project';
}

export interface CreateProjectServerResponse extends IServerResponse {
    cmd: 'otii_create_project';
    data: {
        project_id: number;
    }
}

export type CreateProjectResponse = Project;

export class CreateProjectRequest extends Request {
    constructor(
        transactionId: string, 
        connection: Connection, 
        maxTime: number
    ) {
        super(transactionId, connection, maxTime);
        this.requestBody = {
            type: 'request',
            cmd: 'otii_create_project'
        }
    }

    async run(): Promise<CreateProjectResponse> {
        let serverResponse = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.push(
                this.requestBody, 
                this.transactionId, 
                this.maxTime, 
                resolve as (value: CreateProjectServerResponse) => void, 
                reject
            );
        }) as CreateProjectServerResponse;

        return {
            id: serverResponse['data']['project_id']
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default value for your type parameter.

```
interface ActiveRequest<TServerResponse extends IServerResponse = IServerResponse> {
    resolve: (value: TServerResponse) => void;
    ...
}
```

Now the type parameter doesn't have to be provided.

```
export class Connection {
    ...
    protected activeRequests: Array<ActiveRequest>;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get this error: [ts]
Argument of type '{ transactionId: string; resolve: (value: TServerResponse) => void; reject: (reason: Error) => void; timer: Timeout; progress: ((progress: Progress) => void) | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActiveRequest<IServerResponse>'.
  Types of property 'resolve' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: TServerResponse) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: IServerResponse) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'IServerResponse' is not assignable to type 'TServerResponse'.

Comment: Please create a TypeScript Playground example so we can have a look (otherwise we can just guess): https://typescript-play.js.org/